# WP8 Facebook send message app-to-app

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-phone-8

My question is simple, but I cannot seem to find the answer with Google. I'm working on a Windows Phone 8 app and I would like to offer the possibility to share content with certain people in private. I will add a feature to send by SMS, but I would also like to offer the possibility to send a private message in Facebook.

There is a Facebook app for Windows Phone 8 and I wanted to know if there is a way with "App-to-app" communication to have the Facebook app send the message for me. This way, the user could edit the message and choose who to send it to, without my app having to manage this for him. I think it would be a better user experience than using the Facebook API since it would be consistent.

I looked online and there is a way to make a post. However, that's not what I want since my app handles a financial matters. Is there a simple way to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

It depends not on your App but the Facebook App - if it supports such a feature.

In Windows Phone you can for example associate files and Uri's with certain Apps - [MSDN source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206987%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). By this it is possible (I think somehow) to pass a file (message) to other App (if that App supports it). Other problem may be where to save that file - maybe some webservice as IsolatedStorage is a bad idea.

It will be hard workaround, but surely depend mostly **not** on your App.

In this case I think it will be better to use Facebook API in your App.

Comment: Thanks. I was mostly wondering if anyone had any reference on the WP8 Facebook app to know which URI would be able to do that.

Comment: @gretro I haven't used Facebook API so far - it's hard for me to help you. I only wrote about app-app communication, and my idea (still don't know if it will work) is a complicated workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Use Facebook to do post function like below

```
await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("fb:post?text=foo"));
```

Or you need implement an OAuth flow to get Facebook token then do Post by Facebook post API

https://graph.facebook.com//v2.0/me/feed?message=foo&access_token={TOKEN}

I think these are the possible ways to achieve what you want.